# Как указать шаблон ограничения 'pattern', используя JAXB

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

В xsd у меня есть такое:

`<simpleType name="ID">
        <restriction base="ID">
            <pattern value="[A-Z]{3}[0-9_]{5}"/>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>`

Как написать его в JAXB? Нужно ли создавать отдельный класс ID, вообщем я лишь ищу наилучшее решение, как мне pattern указать, возможно есть способ сделать это с помощью аннотации?